# Синтаксис для выбора значения списка в списке по индексу

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список вида:

```
list = [[a, b], [c, d]]
```

надо из него забирать один элемент, индекс которого известен.

При попытке сделать выборку так:

```
r=list[0[1]]
```

выпадает  ошибка:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Как лучше выбирать значение из двухуровневого списка?

Answer (score 0):

Не называйте список `list`, иначе можно запутаться, назовём его `arr`, вы пытаетесь получить какую-то белиберду, как я понял, вам нужно получить второй элемент первого вложенного списка, а это делается так:

```
arr = [[a,b], [c,d]]
val = arr[0][1]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло.

Comment: @OlehBabanin если ответ помог вам, отметьте его "галочкой"